# How can I flare a part of a model

Tags: modeling

[image]How can I gradually flare out a part of a model smoothly to create a cone expansion on the end of a hollow cylinder trying to create the part in the image

Comment: Hello could you please show an image of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Edited to ad a picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with a cylinder and delete the top face.[image: step one]

Extrude the top ring and scale it out.[image: step two]

Bevel the middle loop using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd>[image: step three]

To thicken the mesh, use a solidify modifier. To round out any other desired edges, use the bevel too. Subdivision surface modifier and shade smooth to taste!

I hope this is able to work for you!